How to use a parameter in a widget in Flutter
I am new with Flutter and now I am wondering how I can use a simple parameter inside my widget.
Here is the code:
class Viewer extends StatefulWidget {
  const Viewer({
    super.key,
    this.width,
    this.height,
    required this.srcURL,
  });

  final double? width;
  final double? height;
  final String srcURL;

  @override
  State<Viewer> createState() => _ViewerState();
}

class _ViewerState extends State<Viewer> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Header')),
        body: const ModelViewer(
          backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(0xFF, 0xEE, 0xEE, 0xEE),
          src: widget.srcURL,
          alt: 'Homer Cool',
          ar: true,
          autoRotate: true,
          iosSrc: 'SOMEURLHERE',
          disableZoom: true,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Now I want to use the parameter srcURL in my widget in src:
I don't know how to, but I've tried many things and this is my most recent try. So far nothing has worked for me.
And the current code gives me the error Invalid constant value.
How to do it in Flutter properly, so I can use the parameter as a variable in the widget.
Many thanks :)
I was using also google and many people used widget.srcURL or $srcURL. I've also tried also other possibilities but I cant get the parameter as a variable in my widget to run.

from const ModelViewer remove const

In 52 lines i really didnt saw that. Now it works, thank you @pskink

The fix for this problem is as simple as removing the const keyword from where you are calling the ModelViewer widget.
class Viewer extends StatefulWidget {
  const Viewer({
    super.key,
    this.width,
    this.height,
    required this.srcURL,
  });

  final double? width;
  final double? height;
  final String srcURL;

  @override
  State<Viewer> createState() => _ViewerState();
}

class _ViewerState extends State<Viewer> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Header')),
        body: ModelViewer( // <<== This part
          backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(0xFF, 0xEE, 0xEE, 0xEE),
          src: widget.srcURL,
          alt: 'Homer Cool',
          ar: true,
          autoRotate: true,
          iosSrc: 'SOMEURLHERE',
          disableZoom: true,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

In dart, if a variable is declared as const, it becomes a compile time constant. However, in your code, the widget.srcURL property would be generated a runtime, hence the error.
The official Dart docs explain this very well.
